# How to Remove all Nodes

Tags: swift, arkit

I am using following code, which works okay removing the most recently created child node. But I want to remove all concerned nodes from the scene

```
self.removeNodeWithAnimation(contact.nodeBit, explosion: false)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the function you need is this:

```
self.augmentedRealityView.scene.rootNode.enumerateChildNodes { (existingNode, _) in
    existingNode.removeFromParentNode()
}
```

In the example `self.augmentedRealityView` refers to the variable:

```
var augmentedRealityView: ARSCNView!
```